# Laravel multiple joins - php

Tags: php, laravel

how can I left join 4 tables in laravel?
This is what I am trying to do:

```
DB::table('table 1')
->join('table 2', 'table 1.field 1', '=', 'table 2.field 2')
->leftJoin('table 3','table 2.id','=','table 3.field 3')
->leftJoin('table 4','table 3.field 3','=','table 4.field 4')
->get();
```

Thanks

Comment: `->join` translates to inner join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace first join with leftJoin like the others, because normal `join` will be `inner join` in your sql query:

```
DB::table('table 1')
->leftJoin('table 2', 'table 1.field 1', '=', 'table 2.field 2')
->leftJoin('table 3','table 2.id','=','table 3.field 3')
->leftJoin('table 4','table 3.field 3','=','table 4.field 4')
->get();
```

Comment: like this I am not getting all the data. only data that exist in the last table. i want to get also data that is in the first two tables but that is not exist in the last one to get null

Answer (score 1):

The following way, you can join as much as you need.

```php
DB::table('table 1')
    ->leftJoin(....)
    ->leftJoin(....)
```

Note:  As normal sql query:

1. join (is inner join)
2. leftJoin (is left join)
3. rightJoin (is right join)

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins